# PHPRedis and Locking

Tags: php, redis, locking

I got the following two functions that I use to lock a Redis key. I am trying to prevent concurrency execution of a block of code using Redis. So what I do is use the following functions in such a way that they prevent the execution of the same code by different threads.

```
lockRedisKey("ABC");
CODE THAT I DON'T WANT TO RUN CONCURRENTLY!
unlockRedisKey("ABC");
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work and causes an infinitely loop at lockRedisKey() until exit_time is reached. What could be wrong?

```
  static public function lockRedisKey($key, $value = "true") {

        $redis = RedisClient::getInstance();

        $time = microtime(true);
        $exit_time = $time + 10;
        $sleep = 10000;

        do {

            // Lock Redis with PX and NX

            $lock = $redis->setnx("lock:" . $key, $value);

            if ($lock == 1) {
                $redis->expire("lock:" . $key, "10");
                return true;
            }

            usleep($sleep);

        } while (microtime(true) < $exit_time);

        return false;

    }

    static public function unlockRedisKey($key) {

        $redis = RedisClient::getInstance();

        $redis->del("lock:" . $key);

    }
```

I'm aware that I might be facing deadlocks, so I decided to use transactions, but I continue to face the issue.

```
    static public function lockRedisKey($key, $value = "true") {

        $redis = RedisClient::getInstance();

        $time = microtime(true);
        $exit_time = $time + 10;
        $sleep = 10000;

        do {

            // Lock Redis with PX and NX

            $redis->multi();
            $redis->set('lock:' . $key, $value, array('nx', 'ex' => 10));
            $ret = $redis->exec();

            if ($ret[0] == true) {
                return true;
            }

            usleep($sleep);

        } while (microtime(true) < $exit_time);

        return false;

    }

    static public function unlockRedisKey($key) {

        $redis = RedisClient::getInstance();

        $redis->multi();
        $redis->del("lock:" . $key);
        $redis->exec();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The locking is working fine. It's just the code between the locking that is crashing and causing the lock not to be released :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your 'exit_time' is too small.
I think the meaning of '$exit_time = $time + 10;' is to turn it off after 10 seconds.
However, the set time is microtime.

Maybe you can replace '$exit_time = $time + 10;' with '$exit_time = $time + 100000;'.
Written by Google Translate

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

First of all, **PHP isn't async script language** as JS f.e. You haven't any control on the script execution ordering, so it means you can't run code that below `lockRedisKey()` call in concurent way.

I assume you're not completely understand what [usleep](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php) function is actually doing, it's just **delay** process and not **postpone** it, so it just blocks process for `$sleep` time and after this continue script execution. So you're not performing concurrent write by calling your script.

Comment: I know, but I’m using PHP FPM, so this piece of code runs concurrently each time a request is sent.